# excel: list all values of a column of a range based on a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range in a Excel Sheet table that contains 2 columns like A and B.
I want to list in another column all values from column A if the corresponding value in column B is not null.
I know a way to do it, but it produces a lot of "empty raws" like in column C

```
=if(B<>"";A;"")
```

I would like to do it in a compact way, with no "empty raws" like in column D

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for data down to row #19.  In **C1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$19,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$19<>"",ROW($B$1:$B$19)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downwards.  *(You may need to use semi-colons in place of commas)*

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]